# How to obtain success validateState with :error in element-ui vuejs

Tags: javascript, laravel, vue.js, vuejs2, element-ui

I create an application with Laravel / Vuejs and Element-ui. In my form, I use the property: error to tell my field that I'm using a Laravel validation.

```
<el-form-item label="Prénom" prop="firstname" :error="registerForm.errors.get('firstname')">
    <el-input name="firstname" id="firstname" v-model="registerForm.firstname">
    </el-input>
/el-form-item>
```

On the following link (http://element.eleme.io/#/en-US/component/form#validation) we can see that when there is an error, the field comes red (it works with me) and when we fill the field correctly, the field turns green.

When there is an error, the validateState data gets the value "error". Using `:error` as validation, when the validation is correct, the property does not pass in "success", which makes it possible to trigger the green field.

How to make validateState pass in success when the error is corrected as in the example of the link?

thank you very much

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to set `is-success` class manually, you can bind `is-success` class to `el-form-item`

```
<el-form-item label="Prénom" prop="firstname" :error="registerForm.errors.get('firstname')"
:class="{'is-success': !registerForm.errors.get('firstname')}">
    <el-input name="firstname" id="firstname" v-model="registerForm.firstname">
    </el-input>
</el-form-item>
```